# Kdenlive isn't displaying effects or compositions in Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, kdenlive

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 and I recently opened up Kdenlive for the first time to work on a new project. I went looking for some effects to add to my clips and found that the effects and compositions tabs display a blank white square.

[No compositions available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QwMV.png)

[No effects available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjb3k.png)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

It's a known bug:

> https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=463203

> https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/zlxl98/did_the_recent_update_break_the_effects_and/

The workaround (worked for me):

```
sudo apt install qml-module-org-kde-kcm
```

Comment: thanks. this is a good question and answer combo!

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the repo version several times with no success I uninstalled and downloaded the flatpak version which works fine.